# How can I wrap my React Navigator in a redux store?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

In my app.js file, I have a Navigator and I am attempting to wrap it in a redux store in order to control the state throughout my app. I am receiving this error though:

"Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation v3 and v4 you must set up your app container directly."

How can I properly wrap my navigator in the Redux store so I can use it?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';


import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import reducer from './store/reducers'

// Components
import Home from './Screens/Home';
import Landing from './Screens/Landing';
import Tasks from './Screens/Tasks';
import Login from './Screens/Login';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
const store = createStore(reducer, middleware)

const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
    Tasks: {screen: Tasks},
    Landing: {screen: Landing},
    Home: { screen: Home },
    

});


export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Navigator />
            </Provider>
         )
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to accomplish this. Below is the updated code with my App wrapped in a store container.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import reducer from './store/reducers'

// Components
import Home from './Screens/Home';
import Landing from './Screens/Landing';
import Tasks from './Screens/Tasks';
import Login from './Screens/Login';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
const store = createStore(reducer, middleware)

const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
    Tasks: {screen: Tasks},
    Landing: {screen: Landing},
    Home: { screen: Home },
    

});

//ADDED THIS
const App_1 = createAppContainer(Navigator);


export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App_1 /> //UPDATED
            </Provider>
         )
     }
 }
```